# Image not showing in browser from SIMPLE HTML CODE

Tags: html, image

Okay you guys I've got a good one for ya. I'm not very familiar with html, but my buddy is and he couldn't figure this out. The image will not show when run on browser with local host. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HUNTER</title>

<h2>HTML Image</h2>
<img src="images/sickBackground.jpg" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">

</html>
```

The image is downloaded locally like so:

```
-images
  |-sickBackground.jpg
-index.html
```

The crazy thing is, when I am typing the location of the image, it SUGGESTS it! And when I run it on a local host, all that shows up is that little placeholder for the image, and I get this in command line:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2020 22:23:19] "GET /images/sickBackground.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I just tried this out and I see no issues

Comment: @WilfredClement could it be some sort of settings in VS code or something?

Comment: I doubt that, Did you try it with a different JPG ? See if that works

Comment: @WilfredClement yeah I tried with a png and jpeg file too :/